# How to connect two personal computers using ssh?

Tags: ssh, remote-login

I have used ssh before to login to a remote server connected via LAN.

I have two personal computers running on Ubuntu. Is it possible to connect the two using ssh so that I can login from one system to another and vice-versa? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

First, make sure package `openssh-server` is installed on both of them. Then, fire up terminal and type:

`ssh username@domain-name.local` - if you are on the same network
or

`ssh username@local-ip` - same as above

or if you are connected to different networks:

`ssh username@public-ip`.

You can also setup password-less connection.
First, generate keys using `ssh-keygen` (you can leave everything default).

Then, copy your public key using
`ssh-copy-id username@domainname.local (as above)`

Repeat the process from the other machine.

Enjoy!